# How do I know my notification is snoozed by user in Android?

Tags: android

In Android Oreo, it introduces the feature of snoozing notifications. The following an example of how to snooze a notification:

[image]

(Figure source: [How to Snooze Notifications in Android Oreo](http://How%20to%20Snooze%20Notifications%20in%20Android%20Oreo))

My question is, is it possible to know that my notification is snoozed? What is the API to access this information?

Comment: Hi did you get any clue about how to solve your problem? I need to be notified too.